# Using a range as a dictionary index in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to do something like:

```
r = {range(0, 100): 'foo', range(100, 200): 'bar'}

print r[42]

> 'foo'
```

So I would like to use a numeric range as part of a dictionary index. To make things more complicated I would also like to use multi-indexes like `('a', range(0,100))`. So the concept should be ideally expandable to that. Any suggestions?

A similar question was asked as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13464143/2075003), but I am interested in a comprehensive implementation as opposed to the different approaches of that question.

Comment: Are the ranges fixed? say all are `range(x*100, (x+1)*100)` for some integer `x`?

Comment: @pseudoDust: Yes, fixed ranges

Comment: I'll post an answer with a simpler and more efficient solution given that relaxation of the problem

Comment: have a look at [this QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict). It works with:  `class RangeDictionary(TransformedDict):  def __keytransform__(self, key):  dk = sorted(self.keys())  return dk[bisect.bisect(dk, key)]`
then `r = RangeDictionary({100: 'foo', 200: 'bar', 250: 'xyz'}); print(r[42]); print(r[142]); print(r[242])` produces `foo bar xyz`. Override `def __getitem__(self, key):  return self.store[self.__keytransform__(key)]` only

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative approach, if you are trying to look up values associated with certain ranges you could use the built in Python [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html?highlight=bisect#module-bisect) library as follows:

```
import bisect

def boundaries(num, breakpoints=[100, 200], result=['foo', 'bar']):
    i = bisect.bisect(breakpoints, num-1)
    return result[i]

print boundaries(42)
```

This would display:

```
foo
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Python 3.x you can use a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) object as key but to retrieve a value you will do something like this:

```
In [33]: r = {range(0, 100): 'foo', range(100, 200): 'bar'}

In [34]: { r[key] for key in r if 42 in key}
Out[34]: {'foo'}
```

The reason you can't do this in Python2.x is because the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#range) function in version 2.7 onwards returns a list and lists cannot be used as dictionary keys because they do not provide a valid [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method.

Comment: Nice, thanks. It is really time to move to Python 3. Unfortunately this project is on 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use immutable datatypes as key. So no Lists.

But you could use a tupel to define the upper and lower bound.

```
r = {(0,100): 'foo', (100,200): 'bar'}
```

I would get the value for 42 this way:

```
res = ""
for (k1,k2) in r:
    if (k1 < 42 and k2 > 42):
         res = r[(k1,k2)]
print(res)
```

But I admit that you don't need a dictionary for that.

Comment: thanks - how would I do `r[42]` now? :)

Comment: added it to my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you have a simple way to calculate the range from a point, for example if all the ranges are of fixed size you can use:

```
def getIndex(p):
   start = floor(p/100)*100
   return (start, start+100)
```

Then have the dict defined:

```
r = {(0, 100): 'foo', (100, 200): 'bar'}
```

and access:

```
r[getIndex(42)]
```

This method is efficient as:

1. You are not holding an item in the dict for each number in the range (this also allows you to have real value "keys")
2. you are not going though the entire dict to find a value, getting a value is O(1)

Also, your `getIndex` function can be more complicated, for example, if your ranges are irregular in there length, your `getIndex` function can binary search a sorted list of range borders and return the range tuple, no longer `O(1)` but `O(log(n))` is not bad...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line

```
r = dict(zip(range(200),["foo"]*100+["bar"]*100))
```

Comment: Very memory inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this :

```
r=dict(zip(range(100),["foo"]*100))
r2=dict(zip(range(100,200),["bar"]*100))
r.update(r2)
```

Comment: Now this is the right way to do it! I'm glad someone highlighted.

Comment: This is inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to get desired dictionary:

```
d = dict([(i,'foo') for i in range(0, 100)] + [(i,'bar') for i in range(100, 200)])
print d
```