# shortening many if-elifs? funcitions in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I ended up with many ugly if-elif's when comparing temperature to determine an adjective for the temperature, I thought that I can look for the temperature value in a list in a dictionary, where its key will be the corresponding adjective for the temperature:

def deternmine_temp(temp):

```
temps = {
    'FREEZING'  : [i for i in range(-20, 0)],
    'very cold' : [i for i in range(0, 6)],
    'cold'      : [i for i in range(6, 11)],
    'chilly'    : [i for i in range(11, 16)],
    'cool'      : [i for i in range(16, 21)],
    'warm'      : [i for i in range(21, 26)],
    'hot'       : [i for i in range(26, 31)],
    'very hot'  : [i for i in range(31, 36)],
    'dangerously hot' : [i for i in range(36, 40)],
    'extremely dangerously hot': [i for i in range(41, 46)]
}

temp = int(temp.replace('°', '').strip())

for word, values in temps.items():
    if temp in values:
        return word
```

This is a lot better than 7+ if-elif's, but I don't think it is very efficient, especially if temps had a lot more data (for example if I had a narrower range of values that correspond to an adjective).

What would be some ways to make this more efficient? Maybe some functions in the dictionary? Above is really the best I can think of.

Comment: This might interest you [use a range as a dictionary key in Python, what option do I have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464143/use-a-range-as-a-dictionary-key-in-python-what-option-do-i-have). Also, [Range as dictionary key in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358092/range-as-dictionary-key-in-python/39358140)

Comment: Just use the `range` objects

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the ranges somehow, and since the ranges don't have the same interval you can't really shorten the dictionary initialization. You can extract the dictionary creation to a function, however you will still have to call it as many times as you have options.

You can however remove the list comprehension from the dictionary and replace the loop with `next`

```
def deternmine_temp(temp):
    temps = {
            'FREEZING': range(-20, 0),
            'very cold': range(0, 6),
            'cold': range(6, 11),
            'chilly': range(11, 16),
            'cool': range(16, 21),
            'warm': range(21, 26),
            'hot': range(26, 31),
            'very hot': range(31, 36),
            'dangerously hot': range(36, 40),
            'extremely dangerously hot': range(41, 46)
            }

    temp = int(temp.replace('°', '').strip())
    return next((word for word, values in temps.items() if temp in values), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to represent temperature as a floating-point number, your code in general will not work. To make sure your code works with non-integer temperatures (just in case), represent ranges as pairs of min-max values and use explicit comparison:

```
temps = {
    'FREEZING'  : (-20, 0),
    'very cold' : (0, 6),
    ....
}

for word, values in temps.items():
    if values[0] <= temp < values[1]:
        return word
```

You may as well use a list of tuples because you do not use dictionary-specific functionality:

```
temps = [
    ('FREEZING', -20, 0),
    ('very cold', 0, 6),
    ....
]

for word, value1, value2 in temps:
    if value1 <= temp < values2:
        return word
```

Finally, for consistency, you may define only the upper range boundary (which simultaneously is the lower boundary of the next range):

```
temps = [
    ('FREEZING', 0),
    ('very cold', 6),
    ....
    ('extremely dangerously hot': float('inf'))
]

for word, value in temps:
    if temp < value:
        return word
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698211/16270364) is closest to what i was looking for.

```
def switch(x):
    return {
            -20<x<=2: 'FREEZING',
            2<x<=5: 'very cold',
            5<x<=10: 'cold',
            10<x<=15: 'chilly',
            15<x<=22: 'cool',
            22<x<=25: 'warm',
            25<x<=30: 'hot',
            30<x<=33: 'very hot',
            33<x<=35: 'extremely hot',
            35<x<=40: 'dangerously hot'
            }[1]

print(switch(40))
```

output:

```
dangerously hot
```

Comment: This is interesting. I have not seen this kind of syntax before. How does it work? Is the part in braces {} a dictionary? If so it's a strange dictionary where the keys will be boolean. Is that even a thing?

Comment: Oh. I sort of figured it out. All of the keys will evaluate to True or False, which is also 1 or 0. So when function is called, you get a dictionary full of lots of False (0) keys and only one True (1) key. In this function, you could replace [1] with [True] and get the same result. Interesting....

Comment: Right, me neither. Never seen this before, but looks about closest i found to what i wanted.

Comment: FWIW, Python 3.10 is supposed to have a switch case statement built in. Only it will be called match case and the full blown official name is Structural Pattern Matching.